# SQL Server performance optimization - Audit Table Redesign

Tags: sql-server, database, database-performance, sqlperformance

I have an Audit table in a SQL server database that with the following columns:

- Sequence --- bigint (primary key)
- TableName --- varachar(50) (nonclustered index)
- ColumnName --- varachar(50) (nonclustered index)
- Control --- char(10) (nonclustered index)
- BeforeValue --- varchar(500) (nonclustered index)
- AfterValue, ---varchar(500)
- DateChanged --- datetime
- ChangedBy --- char(20)
- CompanyCode --- char(5) (nonclustered index)

It has 5 billion+ rows of data. Around 200+ triggers are inserting data in this table and around 50+ stored procedures are inserting as well as querying data from this table. Whenever a column is updated/deleted in any of the 200+ tables in a transactional database, a row is inserted in the Audit table respectively.

I inherited this table recently. We have been experiencing performance issues lately and I am told to redesign this Audit table to address the associated performance problems.

I am looking for suggestions, next steps, performance matrix ideas, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5 billion rows. That's a lot. Quick fix is to archive the old stuff into a different table. Then your updates and other DML won't be as slow. The indexes are obviously playing a part here...

Comment: Part of the issue here is storing a row for each column that changes. Also, there is no need to store the "new" value. It is either the value in the next "previous value" or currently in the table. I have never liked auditing one column at a time. Take a look at your audit data and consider how absurdly difficult it would be to reproduce what an entire table looked like on January 22, 2018 at 11:34am. Good luck with something like that. I much prefer to create a whole row. Sure it take a bit more storage but is much more usable for historical data. And one audit table per base table.

Comment: I understand there's a lot of inserts but what kind of queries are being run on top of this table? Aggregate ones? Also, which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: That seems like a lot of indexes for an audit table (index on a 500 char BeforeValue w/ 5b+ rows?!?).  How often does this data actually get read?  That must be a massive index tree... every insert is probably choking on itself.  IME, audit tables should have only the bear minimum indexes.  If you need high performance reads, snapshot the table in a nightly proc and put your read indexes on the snapshots.

Comment: Agreed, I would look at your non-clustered indexes. Having an NCIDX on a column of nvarchar(500) does not seem right. From a size perspective, that will make the index very large. For sure, you can squeeze performance out of the table by index optimization. For example, index only those columns are used the most in predicates. Also, consider partitioning the table (answer provided).

Comment: Also, check the estimated query execution plan on queries that run the most and show the biggest performance issue. SQL Server sometimes recommends NCIDXs that are non-intuitive, but provide substantial performance improvements, based on the concept of leaf-nodes on the B-Tree (i.e., INCLUDE). https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36815/what-are-the-differences-between-leaf-and-non-leaf-pages

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the solutions, extremely helpful. I have put together everything and evaluating the options. FYI: we are already partitioning the table by month. Most of the queries are inserts from the triggers, few selects are coming in from the applications and reports. Version is  SQL server 2012. We are looking to upgrade to 2016 soon. No one mentioned temporal tables. Is it possible to migrated this table to temporal tables in SQL server 2016 and how beneficial would that be?

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to change much, but just need to redesign your process as follows:

1. Create an archive table exactly the same as your current audit table.
2. Transfer all your current audit able into this new archive table, meaning your current audit table is empty
3. Schedule a daily (or weekly) job to move data from your audit table to the archive table.
4. Based on your data retention policy, clean up your archive table.

But for performance issue, you have to make sure whether inserting into your audit table is really a culprit. If it is, then the above-mentioned way may relieve your pain. Otherwise, it may not help.

Comment: ...and maybe make a view on top of it so the queries are non the wiser which table they pull the data from.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar. If you must maintain the 5 billion records, then your best solution is to partition the table. You will need to do the following:

1. Create partition function
2. Create partition schema
3. Create partition files

The partition function will govern how the data is partitioned: typically it is either by row count (i.e., sequence) or date (i.e., monthly, quarterly, yearly, etc.). Note: partitioning is only available on SQL Server 201X Enterprise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes

I highly recommend that you first read Microsoft's white paper on this before doing anything. Also, once you implement it, this should be done over the weekend to allow for processing as I imagine it will take some time to complete.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580(v=sql.100).aspx

For comparisons sake, a query would not complete after 10 minutes of run time in a pre-partitioned state. After partitioning the table, the query completed within 10 seconds. Note: once the table is partitioned, you will need to tune your queries to include the partitioned column in the predicate. Otherwise, you probably won't notice much of a difference in response times.

Answer (score 0):

You're not highly clear on where the performance issues are: are they in reading the table, or writing to it?  Typically, if the issue is in reading the table, you'll notice a particular area of the system that is slow due to such reads, while if the issue is with writing to the table, you'll have a more subtle performance impact, but will be much more widespread and tends to slow everything down (in varying degrees) instead of just certain hotspot areas.

Another unclear issue is whether this is primarily write-only or heavily read data.  Audit tables are typically write-optimized, to be as fast as they can be for adding new data, while slow to read from it when you do need it (typically we're writing far more often than reading: the opposite of "normal" transactional rows in a RDMS).

Thus, the first step is to determine where the performance issues are, and gather some clues from there to determine whether you need to be optimizing the read portion or the write portion of the table.

If it is indeed a write performance issue (a bit harder to profile and recognize compared to read issues), I would look at perhaps dropping some indexes that are on the table.  I think for a write-optimized table, there's a lot of indexes on there that invoking a lot of overhead on each write operation (remember that each index needs to be maintained with every write to the table, so while indexes are great for reading, they take away write performance: especially nonclustered indexes).

If it is a read issue, I might still opt to write-optimize anyway, then devise some means to improve the read performance as best can be once it's write-optimized.  Other answers here address that in particular, but without being more familiar with the system requirements, it's hard to say which direction is the best to be moving.

Comment: I might also add that I'd much prefer a copy table of each production table subject to auditing, and auditing on a per-row basis rather than the current structure.  You've essentially got the inverse of a One-True-Lookup-Table right now, so if your possible improvements include significant structural changes, such a system is usually far easier to manage.